# VSCode Terminal suggestions not autocompleted

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode's PowerShell Terminal now offers a kind of suggestion in gray of what you might be wanting to type (presumably from the history?):

[image]

But there seems to be no way to actually accept the suggestion: pressing tab just does the normal PowerShell autocomplete (usually of a cmdlet or path).

What is this feature and how can I "tab" to autocomplete the command tantalisingly shown?

UPDATE: Just pressing `right arrow` on the keyboard does the autocompletion.

Comment: How did you achieve that suggestion feature in terminal? I want that too

Comment: Dunno! It's gone now! :-(

Comment: Would anyone know the name of this VS Code feature? I'd like to disable it but I'm unable to find out what the feature's name is.

Comment: It's a PowerShell feature apparently.

Comment: @Marc I had to install the Powershell Extension to get this feature. When I open a Powershell file it also opens a special Powershell Extension terminal with this feature.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For me it was `Shift + RightArrow`.

If you have EditMode VI enabled, then make sure to define whatever key combination you would like to use for this to `SelectForwardChar`. To set `SelectForwardChar` to `Shift + RightArrow` insert the following line of code into your VSCode PowerShell Profile:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Shift+RightArrow -Function SelectForwardChar
```

Comment: So this is a PowerShell feature not VSCode?

Answer (score 17):

The key combination `SHIFT + RIGHTARROW` should do the trick.  I hope this helps!

Comment: what kind of sick demented ... chose such a cryptic way to achieve this.... ??? how are we supposed to guess that ? come on

Answer (score 4):

For me, using simply `RightArrow` already works if my cursor is at the end of the segment I typed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

For me both, `RIGHT→` or `SHIFT+RIGHT→`, works. I am using VS Code v1.86.0 in WIN11 machine.