# VSCode grayed out history commands

Tags: visual-studio-code

We noticed that when you start typing commands in the terminal, it shows you in the background in a light-colored gray the previous history of similar commands you ran in the past. Is there any way to "tab" or similar to autocomplete the command?

Comment: pressing `TAB` will autocomplete the command for you

Comment: Does this answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921867/vscode-terminal-suggestions-not-autocompleted