# How to enable auto guess in VS code new terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run my C program or Python program in the new terminal of VS code I have to type the whole program name there(eg gcc ProgramName.c). But I want the terminal to guess what I'm typing after I typed some letters and then press the right arrow key to complete the name. I used to have it before but I really installed VS code and now I don't know how to enable that.

I've been trying to fix it for 2 days now and can't figure it out. I tried changing the settings in the .json file but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm typing wrong. I typed "terminal.integrated.fileExplorer.autoGuessEnabled": true
But it's not working. please help.

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: Powershell, the default for windows.

Comment: powershell has its own completions feature. check https://stackoverflow.com/q/61921867/11107541 for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VS Code.
2. Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl+,).
3. In the search bar at the top of the settings window, type terminal.integrated.autoGuess.
4. Check the box next to Terminal > Integrated: Auto Guess.
5. Close and reopen the terminal in VS Code.

Comment: When I search terminal.integrated.autoGuess , only one feature is opening which is Terminal>Integrated:Commands to Skip shell. What do I do? I have VS code version 1.87.0. is it the latest version?

Comment: yes , latest version .
open Manage (at left corner) > setting 
in (search setting) type  Integrated: Auto Guess
and now you can see .